# The appearance of the added category in "user services list" page

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I just added a category services(the category name: Like) , but when I go to services list (in user panel), more categories appear before the Like category.
[Please see this video for a better understanding of my problem:](https://ufile.io/j6qyl)

Serviceslist.blade.php codes(in views folder) :

```
@extends('user.layouts.master')
@section('site_title', 'Service List')
@section('page_title')
    <i class="fa fa-list-ol"></i> @lang('slide.serviceslist')
@endsection
@section('body')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @foreach($categories as $category)
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header bg-dark text-white">
                    @if(!empty($category->category)) {{ $category->category->name }} @endif
                    </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Sevice code</th>
                                <th>Service name</th>
                                <th>Price</th>
                                <th>min</th>
                                <th>max</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            @php
                            $items = \App\ServicePrice::where('category_id', $category->category_id)->where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();
                            @endphp
                            @foreach($items as $item)
                            @if(!empty($item->service))
                                <tr>
                                    <td> {{$item->service->id}}</td>
                                    <td> {{$item->service->name}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $item->price }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $item->service->min }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $item->service->max }}</td>
                                </tr>
                            @endif
                            @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

and services list controller:

```
public function serviceList(){
 $categories = ServicePrice::where('user_id', Auth::id())->distinct()- 
 >get(['category_id']);
    return view('user.serviceList', compact('categories'));
}
```

Comment: Let's suppose `$categories` contain several categories, with empty names. Or maybe a magical thing.

Comment: I checked categories table in phpmyadmin, and there is just " Like" category.

Answer (score 0):

You need to order the categories in the controler with categories id to see the last categori as first.

```
public function serviceList(){  
   $categories = ServicePrice::where('user_id', Auth::id())->distinct()->orderBy( "category_id", "DESC" )->get(['category_id']);
   return view('user.serviceList', compact('categories')); 
}
```

Comment: I did it, but show : Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orderBy does not exist.

Comment: order by is before get()

Comment: But now, those additional categories are still appearing!
With your help, the "Like" category came to the first.

Comment: Ok, then what is the problem? I cant see the video and you don't understand well. Your action is insert? list?  if you are creating category you must send to other view, if you  just want to see all the list I gave you the solution, if you want just show one categori use id or put ->fisrt()  and use only one value.,

Comment: No, I added just one category, the category name is "Like", but in "services list" page, after this category, is showing more categories! but they don't have any names or services.